# If the word "dataset" is already included in the acronym, should I still include the word to describe it?

Tags: acronyms

Sorry if the title is a little hard to understand. I'm trying to wrap my head around what the proper usage of a word would be.

I'm writing an academic paper right now regarding COVID-19, and there happens to be a dataset named the "COVID-19 Open Research Dataset," which is "CORD-19" for short.

When I refer to the dataset, I say "the CORD-19 dataset" but what I'm wondering is if the word "dataset" is already included in CORD-19, would it be inappropriate to say "the CORD-19 dataset"since it would technically be "the COVID-19 Open Research Dataset dataset?"

If that were the case, would it be more appropriate to say "the CORD-19?" Thanks.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but I think it feels a bit strange to have "-19" after "CORD" when actually it belongs to the "C" only.

Comment: I'd be tempted to refer to *CORD-19* as *the COVID-19 dataset* if I wanted to focus on the dataset idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The CORD-19 dataset" is OK. It is equivalent to "The dataset named CORD-19". Seeing as CORD-19 is being used as a name, it doesn't matter that the acronym abbreviates a phrase containing the word "dataset". The phrase is similar in this regard to "the corpus BNC" or "the corpus COCA" (British National Corpus; Corpus of Contemporary American English).

Some might see a parallel with e.g. the phrase "an LCD display", a pleonasm for "an LCD" or "a liquid-crystal display". However, the cases are not parallel. LCD is not a name for the particular display the speaker is talking about, but actually *means* "liquid-crystal display"".

Mind you, if you consider both of those phrases acceptable, then the question is moot.